# Azure deployment from GitLab is replacing App_Data folder

Tags: azure, gitlab, continuous-deployment, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have an app service in Azure and I have connected it with my source control on GitLab, everything works fine except one thing. When I deploy from Visual Studio I can tell that App_Data should not be replaced and it works. However, deploying from GitLab (I used this tutorial https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/auto-deploying-to-azure-app-services-from-gitlab/) just replaces all the files with what I have in source control, effectively removing customers data from App_Data.

I presume that this is just simple FTP replace (as I have to run my migrations on App_Start), yet is there a way how to not replace App_Data folder on the app service when deploying from gitlab? Having synchronized App_Data with source control is not acceptable.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by downloading deployment.zip from AppService's Kudu.
Then I edited downloaded deployment.cmd so that KuduSync ignores App_Data.
Then I inserted the modified deployment.cmd and .deployment file to the root of my git folder.